# How do I open GPS settings in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to navigate to the geolocation settings page, however, I get an error "`ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS cannot be resolved or is not a field`" in my code. I have searched everywhere, but couldn't find anything different from what I have done already.-

```
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1);
```

I am running Android 7.0. Is there any other way to do this on my android version?

Comment: try out this: startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))

Comment: same error. I think it's not in my SDK

Comment: final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: same error again

Comment: @RamKoti can you solve this question ?:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796190/how-to-get-device-location

Comment: May be you miss import `import android.provider.Settings;` add that and try it.

Comment: I will try @FatB00B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using wrong import

Use the below import and remove the previous one

```
import android.provider.Settings;
```

Or you can also try like below.

```
Intent settingintent= new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(settingintent);
```